# Continuous deployment strategies vs DevSecOps

Tags: continuous-deployment, security, devsecops

How do you implement security requirements in CI/CD while taking care of security requirements? What are best practices here?

Security requirements may differ, let's assume this simple level of security:

- Direct administrative access to target system shouldn't be given to the CI/CD system
- CI/CD system needs to be able to initiate deployment and show it's success/fail status (could be determined by a white box test routine i.e. without admin access rights placed on the CI/CD side)

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, requirements will differ based on company and industry policy; for us, the adjustment from "separation of duties" to automated deployments has been rough. As interim steps, we've started:

1. Requiring multiple "sign-offs" before deployment; this is accomplished by both reviews for the PR in Azure DevOps and an audit log in Octopus.
2. Monthly review of deployments by higher-ups.  This is mostly a rubber-stamp activity, but it satisfies auditors.